# OAuth: Reduce scope?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to "reduce" scopes in OAuth? Scope reduction should be initiated by the client.
Meaning: Request a new Access Token using the Refresh Token, but the new token has less scopes than the "original" one?

Use case: I'm developing a client application that authenticates users via OAuth with another party (**A**). Now I want to give yet another party (**B**) access to some scopes, but less than I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no standard way to do what you want, but even if there were, you can't often get a new access token without destroying the old access token.

Access tokens are per-client. Once it expires, you can use a refresh token to get a new access token, but many systems are implemented in a way that a refresh token can only be used once and that the original access token immediately (or quickly) expires.

If you control the server, it's definitely possible to implement this as a new, custom grant type, effectively an extension of OAuth2.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6 you should be able to add a scope field on a refresh request, as long as your requested scopes are a subset of the originals and your refresh token is still valid.

Note that the reduced scopes only apply to the access token, so if you leak a long lived refresh token to a third party they can get all the scopes it had.